# Преобразование числа месяца в текстовый формат Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

нужна помощь, вывожу в Laravel с бд запись даты вида 2020-12-03, только месяц 12 но не могу ни как на выходе преобразовать 12 в December.

Код контроллера:

```
 <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use DB;
class EventsController extends Controller
{

  public function __construct()
  {
      $this->middleware('auth');
  }

    public function index()
    {

      $mount = DB::table('events')->selectRaw('substr(event_date,6,2) as event_date')->pluck('event_date')->unique();
      return view('my/events')
      ->with('mount', $mount)
      ;

    }
}
```

Код blade где выводится месяц:

```
<div class="">
  
  @foreach ($mount as $mounts)
        <a>{{$mounts}}</a>
  @endforeach

</div>
```

Comment: `selectRaw('DATE_FORMAT(event_date, \'%M\') as event_date')`

Comment: Мое почтение, спасибо за решение вопроса.